# Is there any difference between these two sentences?

Tags: pronouns, adverbials

What is the difference between "not a bit" and "not one bit"?
I thought they both have the same meaning, but I was wondering if there could be a slight difference meaning between those phrases.

For example, in this excerpt from Steve Jobs' speech 
"the turn of events at Apple had not changed that one bit." 
Can I change the phrase "not changed **that one bit**" to "not changed **it a bit**"?

Another question, is "that" equivalent to "it" in the sentence?

Comment: 1. Your apostrophe is misplaced in *Steve Jobs'*. 2. The usage of *one* in the sentence adds emphasis due to the length of the *o* sound in *one*.

Comment: Sure you can. Plenty of writers [have changed that a bit](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22have+changed+that+a+bit%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl). It's true that rather more writers [have changed **it** a bit](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22have+changed+it+a+bit%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl), but the difference between ***that*** and ***it*** is irrelevant to the ***a/one*** switch.

Comment: Thanks for the correction! :) That was a typo.. I edited the original post.

Comment: @cellardoor: I can't imagine any context where switching ***that*** to ***it*** would change anything, but regardless of which you use, *we don't know what that it refers to* (it's something mentioned earlier in the text, that you haven't given us).

Comment: "... But  something slowly began to dawn on me: I still loved what I did. The turn of events at Apple had not changed that one bit." Here I guess **that**  in the sentence indictates the fact that he still loved what he did. Am I correct? As @Fumble Fingers mentioned, is it okay to switch **that** to **it** in that sentence?

Comment: @cellardoor: It makes no difference whether you use ***that*** or ***it*** - they can both only refer to the preceding statement *I still loved what I did*. Nor does it make a bit of difference whether I use ***a*** or ***one*** in this sentence, really. Except for inscrutable stylistic reasons I generally prefer ***a*** - perhaps because it's more "generic" (it more or less has to be ***a*** in something like *"I didn't do much. I only changed it a bit."*).

Comment: Steve Jobs' original phrasing provides the best interpretation of his thoughts. *That* is more easily related to "*I still loved what I did*" than *it* from a reader's perspective. Both are grammatically correct and neither change the meaning, but the word choice does subtly change the mood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two phrases have the same meaning, however, "not one bit" is somewhat more emphatic, it is also rather more common in American English than British English.